# Post is not defined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Google cloud vm instance to run my node app and i have installed Ubuntu 16.04.6 i have nodejs v11.10.1 installed and npm v6.7.0 installed but when i run app using `node app` it shows `ReferenceError: post is not defined`.I don't know what is wrong here.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{"name": "name",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "app.js",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node app.js",
 "deploy":"gcloud app deploy"
},
 "author": "Faiz Khan",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "bson": "^4.0.1",
 "connect-mongo": "^2.0.3",
 "ejs": "^2.6.1",
 "express": "^4.16.3",
 "express-session": "^1.15.6",
 "fabric": "^2.4.4",
 "jquery": "^3.3.1",
 "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
 "mysql": "^2.16.0",
 "node-fetch": "^2.3.0",
 "npm": "^6.4.1",
 "redis": "^2.8.0",
 "socket.io": "^2.0.3"
}
}
```

Here is my post route:

```
app.post('/chat',(req,res,next) =>{
userName = req.body.usrnm.toUpperCase();  
res.render('classLayout',{user:userName});
});
```

Here is error:

```
ReferenceError: post is not defined
at app.post (/home/equalsignlearning/redis_op/app.js:104:10)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/equalsignlearning/redis_op/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/equalsignlearning/redis_op/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/equalsignlearning/redis_op/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/equalsignlearning/redis_op/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/equalsignlearning/redis_op/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/home/equalsignlearning/redis_op/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/home/equalsignlearning/redis_op/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at jsonParser (/home/equalsignlearning/redis_op/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:101:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/equalsignlearning/redis_op/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

The app works fine on localhost on macos and even on heroku but it only creates problem on ubuntu

Comment: Run `npm install --save-dev nodemon` 
   also include `"preinstall": "npm i -g nodemon"`, to the scripts in package.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to install nodemon package globally to access it in CLI in any directory.
For that matter following is command you need to execute. :

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

And for your "post" error, you need to share the code snippet present in your app.js or in your route file.

Comment: what about post

Comment: It seems you have imported the `app` variable in a wrong manner.
Can you please share the snippet where you declared the `app` variable.

Comment: my app works fine on localhost on macos and even on heroku but it only create problem on ubuntu

Comment: still would like to see the app.js file, if you are ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

The `package.json` does not have `nodemon` has a dev dependence and do not have it installed on the machine already.

1. Run `npm install --save-dev nodemon` this will add **"devDependencies"** to package.json
2. Add `"preinstall": "npm i -g nodemon",` to the **"scripts"** in package.json

package.json

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm i -g nodemon",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy"
  },
  "author": "Faiz Khan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bson": "^4.0.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "fabric": "^2.4.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  }
}
```

Now when you deploy to other machines or other developers get involved the only thing that needs to be executed is `npm install`